# Mount point / symlink for one process only

Tags: linux, symlink, mount

My system has eg a mountpoint at /stuff. I need one particular program to see /stuff as a different mount (the program has hardcoded /stuff paths and I can't change that). Is there a way to have that particular program view /stuff as a different thing to everyone else? Would I have to use chroot, and copy across all the mounts/devnodes etc from my real rootfs? Thanks.

Edit: to clarify, I want one program to see a different place when it looks in /stuff, I don't want the program to access the contents of /stuff via a different place. eg if anywhere else on the system did "ls /stuff" they would see fileA.txt fileB.txt, but if this one program were to do "ls /stuff" it would see fileC.txt.

Comment: Does only this particular have the right to see /stuff under the new mountpoint?

Comment: There are no permissions issues. I just need this one program to see different files inside /stuff.

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged this question with "Linux" I'll assume this is the OS you are asking this for. Depending on the way that particular program gets started you might be able to create a workaround using "`unshare(1)`".

For that you'd have to write a script mounting (or bind mounting) whatever this program needs to `/stuff` and then exec the program. Don't start this script by itself, though. Use "`unshare -m thescriptsname`" and only the process tree starting with the process used by the script will see the new/changed mounts.

Depending on the circumstances starting a shell where you can change the mounts without affecting the system might help, too. "`unshare -m $SHELL`" should give the necessary separation.